# Read/Write Arraylist<java.awt.geom.Area> through socket

Tags: java

How can i send an `Arraylist<java.awt.geom.Area>` through socket ?
because `Area` is not `Serializable` it gives a `NotSerializableException` is there any way to send it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path2D.Float and Path2D.Double are serializable, so you can send one of those instead.

Sending side:

```
void writeAreas(List<Area> areas, ObjectOutputStream stream)
throws IOException {
    List<Path2D> paths = new ArrayList<>(areas.size());
    for (Area area : areas) {
        paths.add(new Path2D.Float(area));
    }
    stream.writeObject(paths);
}
```

Receiving side:

```
List<Area> readAreas(ObjectInputStream stream)
throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    List<?> paths = (List<?>) stream.readObject();
    List<Area> areas = new ArrayList<>(paths.size());
    for (Object pathObj : paths) {
        Shape path = (Shape) pathObj;
        areas.add(new Area(path));
    }
    return areas;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to send a non-Serializable class over a network connection you must provide code to "serialize" it yourself.  This means setting up a serialization encoding/format i.e. convert it to a String or binary representation, writing code to produce this format, and also code that can parse the String/binary representation and recreate an instance of the object.

This means that you must have access to (and encode in your String/binary representation), sufficient internal state to be able to recreate an equivalent object when you deserialize it.  Since `java.awt.geom.Area` doesn't natively support serialization, it's all up to you.

For a simple class it could be sufficient to call `toString()` to serialize and write some simple code to parse that output string to rebuild an equivalent object.  How to do this for a complex class would depend on the internals of the class and is probably beyond what can be explained on SO.

For `Area` this is probably non-trivial since there are so many different `Shape` classes it can represent.